# analysis of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, analysis, operation

Assume a machine has a throughput of 70 ops/s. Say we have an algorithm with time complexity
*T(n) = 2n^2 + 120*

Determine how many hours will it take the machine to execute said algorithm for an input of size *n = 8*.

---

Is this correct?

*T(n) = 2n^2 + 120*

*T(8) = 2(8)^2 + 120*
          = *248* * *70* * *1000*

Please help.

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag it as such.

Comment: 2n^2+120 is not an algorithm. Is this the time complexity analysis of the algorithm? You need to provide more information. Perhaps write the entire question.

Comment: @toky *T(8) = 248 ops*, and you have a throughput of *70 ops/s*; do some dimensional analysis and the answer will be clear.

Comment: @toky: This was closed because questions on StackOverflow are expected to have some value for future users (asking a question someone might ask, investigating an error someone might run into, etc). A question like "Is this answer to an assignment correct" doesn't fit that description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few hints:

- If your program does 70 operations, how many seconds does it take?
- How many seconds in an hour?  (How many seconds in a minute, and how many minutes in an hour?)

Comment: if program does 70 opr it takes 1 second, 3600sec in hour, 60sec in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour . still dont understand

Comment: I'm not doing the homework for you, I'm only giving you hints.

Comment: How about this hint: if a program takes 70 operations, does it take `70*70*1000` hours to finish?

Comment: how about this?  2(8)^2+120=248; 248*70 = 17360; 17360/60 = 289; 289/60=4.8

Comment: Getting closer... suppose T(n)=70.  Try what you just did - do you get the right answer?